# Question regarding decimal LCM

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Two bells ring at hourly intervals of 5/7 and 7/8 respectively. The last time they rang together was at 4 am on Friday, at what time and which day will they ring together again?

I have tried to solve the question by taking the LCM of both the fractions by converting them to decimal but if I take the decimal value upto two places the answer is different than if I take the decimal value upto three places or one place.

Comment: Should we construe "hourly interval of $5/7$" to mean that the time between successive events is $5/7$ hour? $\qquad$

Comment: Consider points of $\frac{1}{56}$ of a hour, starting $4$am Friday

Comment: There seems to be a typo in question they both ring separately with intervals of 5/7 and 7/8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common denominator is $\operatorname{lcm}(7,8) = 56,$ so we observe that
$$
\frac 5 7 = \frac{40}{56} \quad\text{and} \quad \frac 7 8 = \frac{49}{56}.
$$
Then we have $\operatorname{lcm}(40,49) = 1960.$

Thus the next time they both ring simultaneously is $\dfrac{1960}{56}= 35.$